# Smarty - catching "Unable to load template" error

Tags: php, smarty

i use automatic loading .tpl files by get parameter.

The parameter might be wrong and on next move it stops by error "Smarty: Unable to load template".

Can i catch this error and redirect page to some default template?

Thank you very much!

```
$seo = $params[0];
$smarty->display($seo . '.tpl');
```

Comment: Show me your code...maybe you are trying to load a tpl on a different folder

Comment: No, loading is just fine, it works. But sometimes i am trying to load template, which is not exist, and its ok - but i need catch this exception and do action, like load another default template (404.tpl for example). I can verify and catch it by php file_exist function, but i wonder, if Smarty doesnt have own catching this situation.

Comment: Maybe if you try with fetch, instead of display ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smarty has a function to check if a template exists.

From the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.template.exists.tpl):

```
if( !$smarty->template_exists($mid_template) ){
    $mid_template = 'page_not_found.tpl';
}
```

You can for example use it like this:

```
if($smarty->template_exists($template)) {
    header("Location: error.html");
    exit();
}
$smarty->display($template);
```

Comment: I only fill in, that in Smarty 3 is this function called templateExists(). template_exists() id for version 2. You should write this to you reply. Thanks!